# Plot points from \pgfplotstableset

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

i have my MWE

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ Regression}
\framesubtitle{Weight and Height}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
\pgfmathsetseed{1138} % set the random seed
\pgfplotstableset{ % Define the equations for x and y
    create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={42+5*\pgfplotstablerow}},
    create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={(0.6*\thisrow{x}+130)+5*rand}},
}
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x,y}]{10}\loadedtable % create a new table with 10 rows and columns x and y:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[fixed]{\loadedtable}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.8\textwidth}  
Consideremos la variable \textit{Peso} en el eje X , es decir esta es la variable independiente.Y luego consideremos la variable \textit{Altura} en el 
eje Y, es decir, esta es la variable dependiente.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=Weight (kg), % label x axis
ylabel=Height (cm), % label y axis
axis lines=left, %set the position of the axes
xmin=40, xmax=105, % set the min and max values of the x-axis
ymin=150, ymax=200, % set the min and max values of the y-axis
clip=false
]
\addplot[only marks] table {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This tikzpicture works great on article document, but in my beamer stop working.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `beamer` vs. `article` but with the fact that a column is a group, so the `\loadedtable` is not "known" in the right column. This can be solved by defining the table before the `columns`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Regression}
\framesubtitle{Weight and Height}
\pgfmathsetseed{1138}% set the random seed
\pgfplotstableset{ % Define the equations for x and y
    create on use/x/.style={create col/expr={42+5*\pgfplotstablerow}},
    create on use/y/.style={create col/expr={(0.6*\thisrow{x}+130)+5*rand}},
}%
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x,y}]{10}\loadedtable % create a new table with 10 rows and columns x and y:
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.22\textwidth}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[fixed]{\loadedtable}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{0.78\textwidth}  
Consideremos la variable \textit{Peso} en el eje X, es decir esta es la
variable independiente. Y luego consideremos la variable \textit{Altura} en el 
eje Y, es decir, esta es la variable dependiente.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5cm,width=0.9\textwidth,
xlabel=Weight (kg), % label x axis
ylabel=Height (cm), % label y axis
axis lines=left, %set the position of the axes
xmin=40, xmax=105, % set the min and max values of the x-axis
ymin=150, ymax=200, % set the min and max values of the y-axis
clip=false
]
\addplot[only marks] table {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I had to make the left column a tiny bit wider and the plot smaller to avoid overfull hboxes. Needless to say that you could add the regression line with `pgfplots`, too, if needed.